# Python multiprocess spawn process stuck if imported

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, ocr, tesseract, spawn

I am trying to do OCR(Optical Character recognition) on multiple images present in a folder. I am using python multiprocessing module to do it parallely. I am spawning new processes.
When I am running code directly using  python command it works fine but when I import Recogniser class and call process_file, it keeps on spawning new process from calling class.
I tried freeze_support but that didn't help.
Right now to make it work, I am doing subprocess call which is not at all right

ImageRecogniser code:

```
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI
import os
from multiprocessing import get_context, Value
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
import json

from PIL import Image
from itertools import islice

queue_counter = Value('i', 0)


class ImageRecogniser:

    def __init__(self, input_folder_name):
        self.input_folder_name = input_folder_name
        self.total_files = 0

    def get_images(self, extension=(".png",)):
        files_in_dir = os.listdir(self.input_folder_name)
        image_list = [os.path.join(self.input_folder_name, file_) for file_ in files_in_dir
                      if os.path.splitext(file_)[-1] in extension]
        self.total_files = len(image_list)
        return image_list

    def process_images(self, images):

        string_list = []
        api = PyTessBaseAPI()
        for count, image in enumerate(images):
            img = Image.open(image)
            api.SetImage(img)
            output_text = api.GetUTF8Text()
            temp_filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(image)[-1])[0]
            page_number = temp_filename.split("_")[-1]
            print("Processed page : {}".format(page_number))
            output_dict = {"page_number": page_number, "output": output_text}
            string_list.append(output_dict)
        api.End()
        return string_list

    def process_file(self, parallel=False):
        print("Getting images from pdf : {}".format(datetime.now()))
        image_list = self.get_images()
        total_no_of_pages = len(image_list)
        print("Initiating extraction : {}".format(datetime.now()))
        begin_time = datetime.now()
        if parallel:
            available_cpus = len(os.sched_getaffinity(0))
            pool_workers = available_cpus // 1
            if total_no_of_pages > pool_workers:
                size_of_queue = total_no_of_pages // pool_workers
                split_queue = [size_of_queue] * pool_workers
                sum_of_split_queue = sum(split_queue)
                if sum_of_split_queue != total_no_of_pages:
                    pages_left = total_no_of_pages - sum_of_split_queue
                    for i in range(pages_left):
                        split_queue[i] = split_queue[i] + 1
            else:
                split_queue = [0] * pool_workers
                for i in range(total_no_of_pages):
                    split_queue[i] = 1

            # page_ids_list_iterator = iter(page_ids_list)
            print('Split queue : {}'.format(split_queue))
            to_be_processed = []
            start = 1
            for chunksize in split_queue:
                end = chunksize + start
                to_be_processed.append(image_list[start:end])
                start = end
            with get_context('spawn').Pool(processes=pool_workers) as pool:
                result = pool.map_async(self.process_images, to_be_processed)
                output = result.get()
            output = [actual_value for queue_list in output for actual_value in queue_list]
            #json_output = json.dumps(output)
        else:
            output = self.process_images(image_list)
        json_file_name = self.input_folder_name+ ".json"
        with open(json_file_name, "w") as fp:
            json.dump(output, fp)
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = sys.argv[1]
    t = ImageRecogniser(source)
    try:
        current = os.environ["OMP_THREAD_LIMIT"]
    except:
        current = None
    os.environ["OMP_THREAD_LIMIT"] = "1"
    t.process_file(parallel=True) 
    if current:
        os.environ["OMP_THREAD_LIMIT"] = str(current)
```

worker.py

```
import os
import logging
import yaml

from pdf_converter.pdf_to_image import PDFtoImage
from pdf_converter.settings import DATA_FOLDER_PATH, LOGGER_FILE_PATH
from recogniser.image_recogniser import ImageRecogniser
import subprocess

with open(LOGGER_FILE_PATH, 'r') as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
    logging.config.dictConfig(config)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info("STARTING WORKER")
file_name = "4506-T.pdf"
file_path = os.path.join(DATA_FOLDER_PATH, file_name)
logger.info("STARTING PDFTOIMAGE CONVERSION")
pdf_image = PDFtoImage(file_path)
files = pdf_image.run()
logger.info("CREATED {} IMAGE FILES FROM {}".format(len(files),file_name))
image_files_path = os.path.join(DATA_FOLDER_PATH, os.path.splitext(file_name)[0])

# subprocess.call(['python', 'recogniser/image_recogniser_cmd.py', image_files_path])
img_rec = ImageRecogniser(image_files_path)
img_rec.process_file(parallel=True)
```

error

```
2020-07-27 19:57:49,244 - __mp_main__ - INFO - CREATED 53 IMAGE FILES FROM 4506-T.pdf
Getting images from pdf : /home/shashank-mq/project/doOCR/data/4506-T.pdf
Initiating extraction : 2020-07-27 19:57:49.245889
Split queue : [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 114, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/shashank-mq/project/doOCR/worker.py", line 27, in <module>
    img_rec.process_file(parallel=True)
  File "/home/shashank-mq/project/doOCR/recogniser/image_recogniser.py", line 78, in process_file
    with get_context('spawn').Pool(processes=pool_workers) as pool:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 119, in Pool
    context=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 174, in __init__
    self._repopulate_pool()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 239, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 42, in _launch
    prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Please suggest what I am missing and how to do it

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see where it gets stuck?

Comment: It starts multiple process to do OCR and gets stuck. Using subprocess it takes around 10 sec to do OCR whereas here it just hangs. Using top, all cores are being used upto 99% @DmitriiZ.

Comment: And have you tried debugging to see where exactly it gets stuck? Does it get to `process_images` at all?

Comment: It does not get to process images.It keeps on spawning new process. I have updated question

Comment: @ShashankPathak did you find a solution? for me it was a memory issue with no indication, you can see more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784038/python-multiprocessing-application-is-getting-stuck-in-docker-container